# Privileges for Oracle Directory

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying BFILE functionality in Oracle. My plan is all the files should be stored in file server, whose  IP is 192.165.1.10.

Based on this I created a directory in my local PC database like this

```
create directory TEST_DIR as `\\192.165.1.10\c\ATTACH_FILES\STUDENT`
```

Directory is created. My doubt is being my db system and file server are in different locations so should I give any other privileges in Oracle?

Please give your opinion as Bfile is not working properly for me.

Note, my database server and file server are both Windows.

Comment: What OS does the DB server use? Windows? Unix/Linux?

Comment: Also what do you mean "Bfile is not working properly". Specifics are always good. Please describe what actually happens (or does not happen), including any error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

> "My doubt is being my db system and file server in different locations "

That's a very good doubt to have. The database can only access OS directories on its local server, and directories which have been shared  with that server. So you will need to share your file server directory using  `System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares`.

As the database server is Windows you will need to map the shared directory if it isn't mapped already. The mapping must be owned by the OS user that owns the Oracle database, or the mapping owner must grant permissions to Oracle OS user( or its group). So that requires sysadmin access. [Find out more.](http://www.uwec.edu/help/drives/permissions.htm) Also you may have to bounce the database.

Comment: Yes my database server and file server is both windows. The destination folder in file server is shared already, still i cannot read the file using bfile. Please give any solution

Comment: Is the share mapped on the database server?